# Disable Key press event temporarily

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

Is it possible, in GWT, to temporarily suspend a certain key press until it is desired to allow that key press again? Like a global suspension. I have an issue where when I open the date picker on a RelativeDateItem in SmartGWT, that it causes the entire page to scroll out of view until the user hits the UP arrow again.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me for a JEditorPane:

```
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
    if (inTag() > -1) {
        evt.consume();
    }
```

The javadoc shows:

> **void java.awt.event.InputEvent.consume()**
>
> **consume**
>
> public void consume()
>
> Consumes this event so that it will not be processed in the default manner by the source which originated it.

The JEditorPane is in a JFrame which implements KeyListener and the JEditorPane does:

```
jEditorPaneSource.addKeyListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datepicker.addKeyPressHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.KeyPressHandler() {
public void onKeyPress(
    com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.KeyPressEvent event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Not compatible with SmartGWT

Comment: I could do this in the BODY tag, but that would be global and I couldn't communicate to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The problem is that the down arrow is not sent to the control and on a `RelativeDateItem`, it has an autochild for the picker, so it can't be directly accessed nor does it listen for KeyPressEvents. So I was hoping there was a solution where I could tell the browser to ignore those events until the picker is closed, which I can detect.

Comment: I have looked at JSNI and that looks hopeful, but where to capture the keypress?

Comment: Set id to you datepicker, write a javascript function in host page call it on onmodule load.you do your stuff in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can block it with this.

```
         Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler(){
                @Override
                public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
               EventTarget eventTarget = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget();
            Element el = Element.as(eventTarget);
                       switch (event.getTypeInt()){
                       case Event.ONKEYPRESS:
                       case Event.ONKEYUP:
                       case Event.ONKEYDOWN:
                         if (el.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("NODE FROM DATEPICKER")) {
                             if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == "yourKeyCodeToBlock"
                                    event.cancel();
                             }
                         }
                         break;
                       }                   
                }
         });
```